# Woocommerce "out of stock" message

Tags: plugins

By default the "out of stock" message is being output as a `<p>` tag after the product description. How can I change the location where this message is being rendered?

Answer (score 4):

To override the default "out of stock" message that is being outputted as a `<p>` tag, copy:

```
wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/templates/single-product/add-to-cart/simple.php
```

to

```
wp-content/themes/yourtheme/woocommerce/single-product/add-to-cart/simple.php
```

See [edit Woocommerce template files](http://docs.woothemes.com/document/template-structure/)

Open the copied file. On line 17 to 23 you find this code:

```
<?php
    // Availability
    $availability = $product->get_availability();
    if ($availability['availability']) :
        echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_stock_html', '<p class="stock ' . esc_attr( $availability['class'] ) . '">' . esc_html( $availability['availability'] ) . '</p>', $availability['availability'] );
    endif;
?>
```

Here you can change the `<p>` tag to whatever you want. For example, I edited it to:

```
<?php
    // Availability
    $availability = $product->get_availability();
    if ($availability['availability']) :
        echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_stock_html', '<div class="stock ' . esc_attr( $availability['class'] ) . '">' . esc_html( $availability['availability'] ) . '</div>', $availability['availability'] );
    endif;
?>
```

So the output was:

```
<div class="stock out-of-stock">Out of stock</div>
```

#### Important links:

1. [Woocommerce Hooks](http://docs.woothemes.com/document/hooks/)

Comment: Ravs, the idea is "we collect solutions, not links". This guide will help: [answer].

Comment: answer edited try it

Comment: Great improvement! Please leave the steps from your first draft in your answer. They _are_ useful.

Comment: I updated answer link for woocommerce hooks for more info

Comment: @bungeshea thanks for correct me. Next time i'll take care of answers formatting.

Comment: @Ravs your formatting was okay. We just like this site to be the best it can, and so we help out